# Como recuperar varias ações de uma activity para outra?

Tags: android, url, android-activity, intent

Como enviar url de uma activity para outra com diferentes ações de cliques (vários botões)? Tentei usar `intent.putextra` mas não consigo recurar as urls dos outros botões, no caso estou usando duas activity a segunda esta com webview executei com loadurl, mas, como eu disse só consigo fazer que funcione um botão, e não sei como receber os outros na mesma activity.

**enviando assim:**

```
Home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this,INSMainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("hiphop", "https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCUnSTiCHiHgZA9NQUG6lZkQ");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**recebendo:**

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hiphop");
    youtubeView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youtubeView.loadUrl(url);
```

Como visto no código estou tentando carregar gêneros a partir da primeira activity.

Answer (score 1):

Estou utilizando o `Intent` em meu projeto e está funcionando normal, na hora de receber estou recebendo assim:

Crie a variavel `String url` junto com a classe e depois no `onCreate`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            url= extras.getString("hiphop");
        }
```

Dai depois você pode continuar o código

```
youtubeView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youtubeView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: vou testar assim

Comment: @MarcosFreitas Qualquer coisa só falar o que apareceu que tento verificar